# C++ read line by line file with getline

Tags: c++, stream

I want to read a file line by line

```
    void BookRepository::PopulateEntity(Book * book, std::ifstream * inputfileStream)
    {
        getline(inputfileStream, book->Id);
getline(inputfileStream,book->Name);
}
```

Something like this... but I am getting some compilation errors and I don't know why

> Error C2784   'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)': could not deduce
>   template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from
>   'std::ifstream'
>
> Error C2784   'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &&,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)': could not deduce
>   template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from
>   'std::ifstream

Comment: You probably have errors in your code. For one, `inputfileStream` is a pointer, and `getline` expects an object. So change the call to `std::getline(*inputfileStream, book->Id);`. But that's just a guess; without **real code** it's impossible to respond sensibly.

Comment: Show us what type of errors you are getting.

Comment: @PeteBecker the errors come from this line of code.. anyway still getting them

Comment: @PeteBecker oh it seems to work but only with strings...

Comment: @john -- **errors occur in context**. Nobody can compile this code and see the results, so any attempt at explaining the errors is inherently guessing, especially when you say something like "still getting them", which suggests you're now compiling code that's different from the code you posted. You don't have to (and shouldn't) include all of your code, but you should provide a minimal example that shows the problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker The book-> id is int but getline seems to work only with strings ... how can i fix this?

Comment: @john you can either 1) change `id` to a `std::string`, 2) read into a temp `std::string` first and then use `std::istringstream` or `std::stoi()` to get an `int` from that temp string, 3) use `*inputfileStream >> book->Id` followed by `inputfileStream->ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` to ignore the rest of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the format of [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). It puts data in a `std::string`. So your `book->Id` and `book->Name` should be `std::string`.

```
getline(*inputfileStream, book->Id); // if book->Id is string
getline(*inputfileStream, book->Name);
```

Or, you can read into temp strings and later convert them in your preferred data type.

```
string temp;
getline(*inputfileStream, temp);
book->Id = stoi(temp);
getline(*inputfileStream, book->Name);
```